# Migrating data to GCP persistent disk from local linux machine

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, data-migration

I am trying to find commands to copy data from a local linux VM to GCP persistent disk.
I think gsutil cp may be what I am looking for however I cannot find the documentation nor do I know the path to where I would need to copy the data to.

I have seen how to copy to google cloud bucket storage but not to a persistent disk.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to have worked
gcloud compute scp --recurse db/ machineName:/dir/path/